# Use bootstrap grid system with images - image height doesn't adjust

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a two column grid using bootstrap and images. It seems that I manage to divide my space in two columns but this is what happens to my image :

[image]

The width is properly adjusted so that it fits in one column but the height of the image remains the same. How can I fix this? Here's the code I used:

```
<div class="container">
  <hr style="padding:0px; margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px; border:1px solid; border-color:rgb(199,199,50) ;">

  <div class="row">
    <img class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6" src="images\mainOther\firstText.jpg" alt="Flowers in Chania">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not apply `col` classes to images, wrap it in a div and apply the col classes to that; also add `img-fluid` class to the img tom make it responsive as per Bootstrap guidelines

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <hr style="padding:0px; margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px; border:1px solid; border-color:rgb(199,199,50) ;">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Flowers in Chania">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```